# Reading files with Node.js from input file type selector

Tags: html, node.js, file-upload, dropbox-api

I am trying to select files using input file type and then upload them to dropbox using the dropbox Core API or saving it to a local folder using Node.JS readFile and writeFile methods. The problem is that most of these methods require the file path and all I have is the name of the file that is stored in the File object array and for what I have read browsers do not allow to get the full path for security reasons. I don't know how to go about this, can anyone help me solve this? Thanks!!

Comment: There must be a `path` property in your file object.

Comment: All I see are these properties:
lastModifiedDate: Sat May 03 2014 23:11:28 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)
name: "Cookie Holder.jpg"
size: 74514
type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
length: 1
__proto__: FileList
constructor: function FileList() { [native code] }
item: function item() { [native code] }
__proto__: Object

Comment: I'm not talking about client side file object. It's about server-side node-js file object. When you upload file to the server, node-js request object contains the file object you've sent, with temporary file path, which then you can use to send this file to your `dropbox-api` or move it to your server directory.

Comment: My problem is I don't know how to upload it to Node.js in the first place without the client-side path do I have to use FileReader?